# Double is not abstract and does not override abstract method getNext() in ListInterface?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm trying to compile the following program and keep receiving an abstract method error. The program I'm trying to compile is as follows (not yet complete though). The error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Double.java:5: error: Double is not abstract and does not override abstract method getNext() in ListInterface
public class Double<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ListInterface<T>{
       ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in class Double
1 error
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import ch06.lists.*;
import support.DLLNode;

public class Double<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ListInterface<T>{

    protected DLLNode<T> front;
    protected DLLNode<T> rear;
    protected DLLNode<T> curPosition;
    protected int numElements;

    public Double(){
        front = null;
        rear = null;
        curPosition = null;
        numElements = 0;
    }

    protected DLLNode<T> find(T target){

    }

    public int size(){
        return numElements;
    }

    public boolean contains(T element) throws NullPointerException{
        if (DLLNode.getInfo()!=element){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(T target) throws StackUnderflowException{
        if (!contains(target)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
            DLLNode.setLink()==null;
        }
    }

    public T get(T element){
        return find(element);
    }

    public String toString(){

    }   

    public void reset(){

    }

    @Override
    public T getNext(){
        return null;
    }

    public void resetBack(){

    }

    public T getPrevious(){

    }

    public void add(T element){

    }
}
```

Comment: Add @Override to all your overriden methods. It can help you understand

Comment: Can you give use the code for ListInterface.java?

Comment: @baraky Use <ctrl-f> to find "getNext" :)

Comment: I guess getNext() doesnt really override the needed method. Adding @Override will point that out easily.

Comment: Even with editing the code to `@Override` it, I still get the same error message.

Comment: Ampage Grietu, we all are waiting for ListInterface sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of errors here.

Some:

1.

```
 protected DLLNode<T> find(T target){
```

needs to return something.

2.

```
 public String toString(){
```

needs to return something.

3.

```
public T getPrevious(){
```

needs to return something.

4.

```
    protected DLLNode<T> find(T target) {
```

while

```
    public T get(T element) {
        return find(element);
    }
```

see that get() returns T and find() returns `DLLNode<T>`

---

Compiler just got confused with all that and told you to fix at least something :)

Answer (score 0):

It says you are not overriding the `getNext()` method in `ListInterface`, and currently you have two `getNext()` methods. I'm surprised it's not telling you about that, but I guess it's looking at the first one and seeing it's not the same as what it expects from `ListInterface.java`. Delete the `public DLLNode<T> getNext()` method, and the error should go away.

The real solution to your problem is to get yourself a good IDE, like Eclipse or IntelliJ. They will highlight where all the problems are in your code and give you suggestions on how to fix them. Generally the hardest part in using an IDE is getting it set up properly, so I'd suggest doing a search for a tutorial for whatever IDE you decide.

Comment: I won't say delete since it could be an overloading of the method. Still, is a wrong overload.

Comment: I didn't notice that I did that, but even when I delete the one method I still get the error. I have the `@Override` used.

Comment: I am currently using Geany as my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

You are missing a } at:

```
public boolean remove(T target) throws StackUnderflowException{
    if (DLLNode.contains()==target){
        return true;
        DLLNode.setLink()==null;
}
```

Although I don't really understand what you try to do here...

in:

```
   public boolean remove(T target) throws StackUnderflowException{
        if (!contains(target)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
            DLLNode.setLink()==null;
        }
    }
```

You cannot return a value and execute another command after. Switch the order of return & `DLLNode.setLink()==null;`

Comment: Strange that I missed that, but even changing my code to include it leads me to the same error.

Comment: I think you have many errors. What does DLLNode.contains()==target means?

Comment: So there's the error. Are you sure you get the same error? I suggest you remove all the methods internal code and try to look for the error from the begining

Comment: Still, it should throw other errors and not an error for the class. That's the main reason I'm trying to compile it.

Comment: what do you mean? If you have syntax error, you need to fix it first.